# Copy values in all rows and columns without the formulas

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-formula

I have a scenario where i have an excel sheet with a lot of formulas applied on it. I want to copy all the cell values (rowsxcols) to another excel file.

[image]

The actual file has a lot of rows and columns and a lot of formulas. I only want to copy the values.

I have searched the web didn't try any code. A little bit of spoon feeding here is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Click on the to left corner of your sheet to select all cells. Copy to clipboard. Go to the target excel file. Then Paste Special ->  Values.

Comment: thanks for your time @Alexey is there a way i can do it in an automated way like the macro

Comment: Alt + T, M, R records a macro.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub main()
    With Workbooks("SourceWbName").Worksheets("SourceShtName").UsedRange
        Workbooks("TargetWbName").Worksheets("TargetShtName").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Column.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Just change all workbooks and worksheets names to your actual ones

Target workbook must be already open at the monent you run this code

Comment: @dakait, did you get through it?